# Replace of HTML Content using SQL UPDATE

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am working on some Patch Update statements which I want to use to update content data to the new software version.
So I have a database for version X and want to update the content to version Y.

Inside the database I have tables with fields (:type text or varchar) including HTML content.

There a hyperlinks which I need to update to a new kind of url.

Example:

```
<a href="_UpInclude/scriptEx/__TQinfoBaseImage.asp?rq_RecordId=28177&rq_MasterId=28177&rq_Revision=1">Link1</a>
```

New:

```
<a href="/ror/current/28177.image">Link1</a>
```

So I need to find a links (case insensitive), grab the Id and replace them with the new link.
So I am looking for a "regex" replacement, but I don't find any informationen about it so far.

Something like:

```
UPDATE table 
SET field = RegExReplace(content_column,
                         '.*__TQinfoBaseImage.asp?.*rq_MasterId=(\d+).*',
                         '/ror/current/(\d+).image')
```

Anyone know how todo this ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives exactly what you need. First of all create the function. I am using your data for the example.

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[RegexReplace]
(
  @pattern VARCHAR(255),
  @replacement VARCHAR(255),
  @Subject VARCHAR(4000),
  @global BIT = 1,
 @Multiline bit =1
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
/*MORE DETAILS @ http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-    workbench/ */

AS BEGIN
DECLARE @objRegexExp INT,
    @objErrorObject INT,
    @strErrorMessage VARCHAR(255),
    @Substituted VARCHAR(8000),
    @hr INT,
    @Replace BIT

SELECT  @strErrorMessage = 'creating a regex object'
EXEC @hr= sp_OACreate 'VBScript.RegExp', @objRegexExp OUT
IF @hr = 0 
    SELECT  @strErrorMessage = 'Setting the Regex pattern',
            @objErrorObject = @objRegexExp
IF @hr = 0 
    EXEC @hr= sp_OASetProperty @objRegexExp, 'Pattern', @pattern
IF @hr = 0 /*By default, the regular expression is case sensitive. Set the IgnoreCase  property to True to make it case insensitive.*/
    SELECT  @strErrorMessage = 'Specifying the type of match' 
IF @hr = 0 
    EXEC @hr= sp_OASetProperty @objRegexExp, 'IgnoreCase', 0
IF @hr = 0 
    EXEC @hr= sp_OASetProperty @objRegexExp, 'MultiLine', @Multiline
IF @hr = 0 
    EXEC @hr= sp_OASetProperty @objRegexExp, 'Global', @global
IF @hr = 0 
    SELECT  @strErrorMessage = 'Doing a Replacement' 
IF @hr = 0 
    EXEC @hr= sp_OAMethod @objRegexExp, 'Replace', @Substituted OUT,
        @subject, @Replacement
 /*If the RegExp.Global property is False (the default), Replace will return the @subject string with the first regex match (if any) substituted with the replacement text. If RegExp.Global is true, the @Subject string will be returned with all matches replaced.*/   
IF @hr <> 0 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Source VARCHAR(255),
            @Description VARCHAR(255),
            @Helpfile VARCHAR(255),
            @HelpID INT

        EXECUTE sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objErrorObject, @source OUTPUT,
            @Description OUTPUT, @Helpfile OUTPUT, @HelpID OUTPUT
        SELECT  @strErrorMessage = 'Error whilst '
                + COALESCE(@strErrorMessage, 'doing something') + ', '
                + COALESCE(@Description, '')
        RETURN @strErrorMessage
    END
   EXEC sp_OADestroy @objRegexExp
   RETURN @Substituted
END


--EXAMPLE
DECLARE @YourLink AS VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @YourLink = '<a href="_UpInclude/scriptEx/__TQinfoBaseImage.asp?   rq_RecordId=28177&rq_MasterId=28177&rq_Revision=1">Link1</a>'

SELECT  '<a href="/ror/current/' + 
        dbo.RegexReplace('.*__TQinfoBaseImage.asp?.*rq_MasterId=(\d+).*', '$1',@YourLink,1,1)
    + '.image">' 
    + dbo.RegexReplace('<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)</ ?a>', '$1',@YourLink,1,1) 
    + '</a>'
```

/* Replace @YourLink With the data col name to get the results and update */

Comment: When i change @ subject and @ substituted to varchar(MAX) it don't work any more. The version from the source link I tried as well and don't work at all. Any idea? At the moment it limits my content to 4000 chars, but my content has more chars. And what happens if I have more then one link inside a content, does it replace both ?

Comment: You can make `@Subject VARCHAR(max)` and `RETURN VARCHAR (max)`. If you can find the correct regular expression funtion will replace the multiple links. For example 'SELECT   dbo.RegexReplace('</?\w+\s+[^>]*>','<a href="/ror/current/' + '$1'+'.image">' ,@YourLink,1,1)' But this cannot find the group pattern you are searching for. Look for only the first part '<a...'> of the anchor

Answer (score 0):

As I had problems with the size limit of the above solution I continue to search and found this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19502/A-T-SQL-Regular-Expression-Library-for-SQL-Server

I am using SQL 2005/8, So CLR works for me.
This componente does fast and exactly what I needed.

Example:

```
DECLARE @text varchar(max);
SET @text = '<img src="../../../_UpInclude/scriptEx/__TQinfoBaseImage.asp?rq_RecordId=1696&rq_MasterId=16196&rq_Revision=2" height="369" width="260" />
             <b>some text</b>
             <img src="../../../_UpInclude/scriptEx/__TQinfoBaseImage.asp?rq_RecordId=1696&rq_MasterId=1696&rq_Revision=2" height="369" width="260" />
             <p>some html</p>
             <img src="../../../_UpInclude/scriptEx/__TQinfoBaseImage.asp?rq_RecordId=1696&rq_MasterId=21696&rq_Revision=2" height="369" width="260" />'

SELECT dbo.ufn_RegExReplace(CAST(@text AS varchar(MAX))
                        , '[^"]*__TQinfoBaseImage.asp?.*rq_MasterId=(\d+)[^"]*'
                        , '/ror/current/$1.image'
                        , 1)
```

So for all that have the same issue, you can choose now two solutions.